# short exact sequences of linear algebraic groups and $K$-forms

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

This is probably a stupid question, but I can't figure it out.

Let $G, G', G''$ be linear algebraic groups over a characteristic $0$ field $K$. Say that $G' \in A$ and $G'' \in B$, where $A,B$ are subsets of the set of linear algebraic $K$-groups such that $A,B$ are closed under taking $K$-forms. Suppose also that there is a short exact sequence $1 \to G' \to G \to G'' \to 1$. Now let $H$ be a $K$-form of $G$.

> Is it true that there is a short exact sequence $1 \to H' \to H \to H \to 1$ such that $H' \in A$ and $H'' \in B$?

Comment: I can't figure out the meaning of the question. What is $k$?  If $k$ is an extension of $K$, what does it mean "closed under taking $K$-forms" within $k$-defined groups?

Comment: @YCor $k$ should be $K$. I've fixed the typo.

Comment: OK, but for a $K$-group, I don't guess what you mean by "taking $K$-forms". A $K$-group is already a $K$-form...

Comment: It's pretty standard to say $K$-forms (or just forms, or twisted forms) instead of $\bar{K}/K$-forms.